# Does cookies() function in nextjs 13.4 replace the '_' symbol by a space ' '?

Tags: next.js13

I am using nextjs 13.4. I want to send cookies while doing serverside fetch. I can see that I need to manually send those cookies or please let me know if I don't. However, when I try to use cookies() function to get all cookies to send them manually in Cookie header, it just has the cookies but the '_' symbol is replaced by a space ' '. I didn't check all those, but I think that one symbol is enough to wrong that cookie. Let me know if I missed something.

I repeat, I tried to use cookies() function to get those cookies and send those manually while fetching. I expected all those cookies sent in 'Cookie' header while doing fetching.